# how do i Retrieving the phone number from the file by giving the name for example : Enter name: chris phone number: 012222222

Tags: java

```
 Chris
0122222222
Kathryn
0122222222
Jean
0122222222
swaggy
0122222222
```

i have succesfull run the textfile and it show me this result . Now, how do i Retrieving the phone number from the file by giving the name for example :

Enter name: chris
phone number: 012222222

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to include some code

Comment: Deserialize the text file into a list of objects (likely custom deserialization logic, but reading a text file in Java is pretty straightforward).  Then select the object you want from that list.

Comment: Also, please edit title as more generic, because it is so specific.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, these links will be helpful for read data from file:

[Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

[Reading and displaying data from a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731365/reading-and-displaying-data-from-a-txt-file)

Secondly, these links will be helpful for get input from command line:

[How to get input via command line in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914676/how-to-get-input-via-command-line-in-java)

[How can I get the user input in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-can-i-get-the-user-input-in-java)

And the last, a simple code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("list.txt"))) {

      String sCurrentLine;
      while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        list.add(sCurrentLine.trim());
      }

      System.out.print("Enter name: ");
      String name = scanner.next();
      for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String s = list.get(i);
        if (s.equals(name.trim())) {
          System.out.println("phone number: " + list.get(i + 1));
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```